# nth term of series

Tags: c++, algorithm, series

we have to find the nth term of this series http://oeis.org/A028859

n<=1000000000

answer should be modulo 1000000007

i have written the code but time limit exceeds when n  a is huge number.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    cin>>n;

    long long int a,b,c;
    a=1;
    b=3;

    int i;
    for(i=3;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c=(2ll*(a+b))%1000000007;
        a=b;
        b=c; 
    }

    cout<<c;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could paste in a cleaner code sample than this one, using proper indentation and avoiding the excessive white space?

Comment: What does this have to do with dynamic programming?

Comment: Try the recursive version of this algorithm and you'll understand how this is a dynamic programming algorithm. Basically, we store the computed values of n-1 and n-2. Let's say, it's a basic verson of DP.

Comment: Two simple optimizations -- you can start out doing three steps for each iteration in your loop with no copies, doing "c=2(a+b)..." "b=2(c+a)..." "a=2(b+c)...". You can also then do the mod only once per loop, on c in the first step. That should more than double your speed.

Comment: it's not related to DP. DP is about finding the optimum in a decision problem. this is just recursion

Comment: ? sorry dude, you are misunderstand the DP meaning. Dp is about storing computed values in order to use them in futur computation and not having to compute them again.

Comment: @lcfseth no it's not, well partly, but still: no. you're talking about memoization.

Comment: The key idea behind dynamic programming is quite simple. In general, to solve a given problem, we need to solve different parts of the problem (subproblems), then combine the solutions of the subproblems to reach an overall solution. Often, many of these subproblems are really the same. The dynamic programming approach seeks to solve each subproblem only once, thus reducing the number of computations: once the solution to a given subproblem has been computed, it is stored or "memo-ized": the next time the same solution is needed, it is simply looked up.

Comment: Good, now with this explanation of DP, can you please explain why anyone in the right mind would try DP with THAT problem? It obviously cannot be any faster than the simple recursion, since there are the same a(n)'s to be calculated. In fact, it will be slower because of branches in the code.

Comment: The recursive form of the fibonnaci number complexity is O(2^n) where the complexity of the DP is O(n). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: The intelligent form of recursive fibonacci is doing it from the bottom up which is also O(n) and without any branches, thus faster.

Comment: @lcfseth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184869/what-is-difference-between-memoization-and-dynamic-programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard technique for solving this type of problem is to rewrite it as a matrix multiplication and then use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to efficiently compute powers of the matrix.

In this case:

```
a(n+2) = 2 a(n+1) + 2 a(n)
a(n+1) = a(n+1)

(a(n+2)) = (2  2) * ( a(n+1) )
(a(n+1))   (1  0)   ( a(n)   )
```

So if we define the matrix A=[2,2 ; 1,0], then you can compute the n th term by

```
[1,0] * A^(n-2) * [3;1]
```

All of these operations can be done modulo 1000000007 so no big number library is required.

It requires O(log(n)) 2*2 matrix multiplications to compute A^N, so overall this method is O(log(n)), while your original method was O(n).

EDIT

[Here](http://wilanw.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/matrix-exponentiation.html) is a good explanation and a C++ implementation of this method.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26281100/461597) I've answered a similar question, but additionally utilising Euler's Theorem. 1000...07 is a prime number, so you don't have to compute A^N but A^(N % (p-1)) is enough. That way the method becomes O(1) (or O(p) but p is constant) instead of O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

When `long long` is not enough, you probably want to use a bignum library. For example [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: but we have to give answer modulo 1000000007

Comment: Not only is **long long int** enough but I belive **unsigned long int** is also sufficient since the max possible value is 4*10000007 < 4294967295.