# Is Memoization considered Dynamic Programming?

Tags: java, c++, dynamic

I'm confused about what the difference between dynamic programming and memoization is. I always thought they were the exact same thing, just different words, but if this isn't the case, could somebody please clarify what they mean?
Google gives me different answers every time I click on a different blog.

Comment: Memoization is a common **optimization** with dynamic programming, but it is not *synonymous* with dynamic programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between memoization and dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184869/what-is-the-difference-between-memoization-and-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 4):

Relevant article on Programming.Guide: [Dynamic programming vs memoization vs tabulation](http://programming.guide/dynamic-programming-vs-memoization-vs-tabulation.html)

---

> ***What is difference between memoization and dynamic programming?***

**Memoization** is a term describing an optimization technique where you cache previously computed results, and return the cached result when the same computation is needed again.

**Dynamic programming** is a technique for solving problems of recursive nature, iteratively and is applicable when the computations of the subproblems overlap.

Dynamic programming is *typically* implemented using tabulation, but can also be implemented using memoization. So as you can see, neither one is a "subset" of the other.

---

A reasonable follow-up question is: **What is the difference between tabulation (the typical dynamic programming technique) and memoization?**

When you solve a dynamic programming problem using tabulation you solve the problem "**bottom up**", i.e., by solving all related sub-problems first, typically by filling up an *n*-dimensional table. Based on the results in the table, the solution to the "top" / original problem is then computed.

If you use memoization to solve the problem you do it by maintaining a map of already solved sub problems. You do it "**top down**" in the sense that you solve the "top" problem first (which typically recurses down to solve the sub-problems).

A good slide from <strike>[here](http://web2.cc.nctu.edu.tw/~claven/course/Algorithm/unit13.ppt)</strike> (link is now dead, slide is still good though):

> - If all subproblems must be solved at least once, a bottom-up dynamic-programming algorithm usually outperforms a top-down memoized algorithm by a constant factor
>
>   - No overhead for recursion and less overhead for maintaining table
>   - There are some problems for which the regular pattern of table accesses in the dynamic-programming algorithm can be exploited to reduce the time or space requirements even further
> - If some subproblems in the subproblem space need not be solved at all, the memoized solution has the advantage of solving only those subproblems that are definitely required

**Additional resources:**

- Wikipedia: [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)
- Related SO Q/A: [Memoization or Tabulation approach for Dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042356/memoization-or-tabulation-approach-for-dynamic-programming)

Source: [What is the difference between memoization and dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184869/what-is-the-difference-between-memoization-and-dynamic-programming)

Comment: Additionally, for dp, some problem doesn't require to keep the whole table, only last columns might suffice (discarding so previous results, that memoization don't)