# Dynamic algorithm to find maximum sum of products of "accessible" numbers in an array

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic, numbers, divide-and-conquer

I have been asked to give a *dynamic* algorithm that would take a sequence of an even amount of numbers (both positive and negative) and do the following:

Each "turn" two numbers are chosen to be multiplied together. The algorithm can only access either end of the sequence. However, if the **first** number chosen is the leftmost number, the **second** number can be either the rightmost number, or the new leftmost number (since the old leftmost number has already been "removed/chosen") and vice-versa. The objective of the program is to find the maximum *total sum* of the products of the two numbers chosen each round.

**Example:**

> Sequence: { 10, 4, 20, -5, 0, 7 }
>
> Optimal result: 7*10 + 0*-5 + 4*20 = **150**

**My Progress:**

I have been trying to find a dynamic approach without much luck. I've been able to deduce that the program is essentially only allowed to multiply the end numbers by the "adjacent" numbers each time, and that the objective is to multiply the smallest possible numbers by the smallest possible numbers (resulting in either a double negative multiplication - a positive number, or the least-smallest number attainable), and continue to apply this rule each time right to the finish. Contrastingly, this rule would also apply in the opposite direction - multiply the largest possible numbers by the largest possible numbers each time. Maybe the best way is to apply both methods at once? I'm not sure, as I mentioned, I haven't had much luck implementing an algorithm for this problem.

Comment: Writing a recursive algorithm to check every possibility is quite easy; however, this will check the same sequences many times: in your example there are three different ways to arrive at the last step {20,-5}. To avoid calculating this three times, you'd calculate the result for short sub-arrays first, store the result, and then use this to solve larger parts of the array.

Comment: For an array of 20 numbers, a simple recursive algorithm needs 29,524 recursions, whereas an algorithm that builds up from smaller parts to larger parts (also see dfb's answer) only needs to calculate 100 cases (19 + 17 + ... + 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at both a recursive and a bottom-up tabulated approach. First the recursive:

```
{10, 4,20,-5, 0, 7}

First call:

  f(0,5) = max(f(0,3)+0*7, f(2,5)+10*4, f(1,4)+10*7)

Let's follow one thread:

  f(1,4) = max(f(1,2)+(-5)*0, f(3,4)+4*20, f(2,3)+4*0)
```

`f(1,2)`, `f(3,4)`, and `f(2,3)` are "base cases" and have a direct solution. The function can now save these in a table indexed by `i,j`, to be accessed later by other threads of the recursion. For example, `f(2,5) = max(f(2,3)+0*7...` also needs the value for `f(2,3)` and can avoid creating another function call if the value is already in the table. As the recursive function calls are returned, the function can save the next values in the table for `f(1,4)`, `f(2,5)`, and `f(0,3)`. Since the array in this example is short, the reduction in function calls is not that significant, but for longer arrays, the number of overlapping function calls (to the same `i,j`) can be much larger, which is why memoization can prove more efficient.

The tabulated approach is what I tried to unfold in my other answer. Here, instead of a recursion, we rely on (in this case) a similar mathematical formulation to calculate the next values in the table, relying on other values in the table that have already been calculated. The stars under the array are meant to illustrate the order by which we calculate the values (using two nested `for` loops). You can see that the values needed to calculate the formula for each `(i,j)`-sized subset are either a base case or exist earlier in the loop order; these are: a subset extended two elements to the left, a subset extended two elements to the right, and a subset extended one element to each side.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a **dynamic programming** algorithm.  Let `A` be the array of numbers, the recurrence for this problem will be

```
f(start,stop) = max( // last two numbers multiplied + the rest of sequence,
                     // first two numbers multiplied + the rest of sequence,
                     // first number*last number + rest of sequence  )
```

f(start,stop) then is the optimal result for the subsequence of the array beginning at start,stop. You should compute f(start,stop) for all valid values using dynamic programming or memoization.

Hint: The first part `// last two numbers multiplied + the rest of sequence` looks like:

```
 f(start,stop-2) + A[stop-1]*A[stop-2]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `f(start,stop-2)` in the last line?

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense! Btw, do you know a convenient way to store the multiplications each time so I don't end up computing the same multiplication twice? I can't think of a good way of doing it..

Comment: @user3495690 I could post my javascript code for this if you want me to, but you should be able to figure it out with the answers you have now.

Comment: @m69 I think I understand, I'm just not sure how to store which values are being multiplied to avoid calculating the multiplication multiple times and make it a *dynamic* algorithm. Would you be able to give a good method to accomplish this?

Comment: @user3495690 There are a number of options, the most obvious of which is solving every sub-array of length 2 and storing the results in an array, and then solving every sub-array of length 4 using the stored results, then solving every subarray of length 6, and so on... For a discussion of whether this amounts to dynamic programming and/or memoization and/or tabulation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184869/what-is-difference-between-memoization-and-dynamic-programming

Comment: @m69 So just to clarify - do you mean to use a 2-dimensional array to store the results each time, and if the array for the particular indexes (say A[i][j] where i is the index of the first number, and j is the index of the second number to be multiplied) is already filled (thus, *calculated*), use the value at that index. Otherwise, fill that index with the new value?

Comment: @user3495690 I mean you calculate and store all the length-2 values in a 1D array, and use these to calculate and store all the length-4 values; then you can throw away the length-2 values, and use the length-4 values to calculate the length-6 values, and so on. You don't need to keep all the results for every level; once the length-4 values have been calculated, you have no more use for the length-2 values. You work your way up gradually from short sub-arrays to the whole array; that is the aspect of the solution that makes it dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

Let `i` and `j` represent the first and last indexes of the array, `A`, after the previous turn. Clearly, they must represent some even-sized contiguous subset of `A`. Then a general case for `dp[i][j]` ought to be `max(left, right, both)` where `left = A[i-2]*A[i-1] + dp[i-2][j]`, `right = A[j+1]*A[j+2] + dp[i][j+2]`, and `both = A[i-1]*A[j+1] + dp[i-1][j+1]`; and the solution is `max(A[i]*A[i+1] + dp[i][i+1])` for all `i` except the last.

Fortunately, we can compute the dp in a decreasing order, such that the needed values, always representing larger surrounding subsets, are already calculated (stars represent the computed subset):

```
{10, 4,20,-5, 0, 7}
  *  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *
  *  *
     *  *  *  *    (70)
     *  *
        *  *  *  *
        *  *
           *  *    left = (80 + 70)
              *  *
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet of recursive approach.

```
  public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {10, 4, 20, -5, 0, 7};
    System.out.println(findMaximumSum(arr, 0, arr.length - 1));
  }

  private static int findMaximumSum(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (end - start == 1)
        return arr[start] * arr[end];

    return findMaximum(
        findMaximumSum(arr, start + 2, end) + (arr[start] * arr[start + 1]), 
        findMaximumSum(arr, start + 1, end - 1) + (arr[start] * arr[end]),
        findMaximumSum(arr, start, end - 2)+ (arr[end] * arr[end - 1])
        );
  }

  private static int findMaximum(int x, int y, int z) {
    return Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z);
  }
}
```

The result is 10*4 + 20*7 + -5*0 = 180

and similarly for the input {3,9,7,1,8,2} the answer is 3*2 + 9*8 + 7*1 = 85

Comment: This uses the incorrect heuristic that the optimal choice between the three options at any one time will also be the optimal choice in the long run. Consider [3,9,7,1,8,2]; your algorithm will result in 3*9 + 8*2 + 7*1 = 50, while the optimal answer is 3*2 + 9*8 + 7*1 = 85.

Comment: @m69 Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Corrected the solution.

Comment: As an exercise I solved this problem with every approach I could think of (enumeration, simple recursion, tabulation, memoization, heuristics) and so far I haven't found an approach that doesn't try every possibility and returns the correct result. A heuristic which makes a decision based on the 4, 6, 8... outer numbers can never find the correct solution for a case like [-1,1,1,1...-99...1,1,1,-1] which is to save one of the -1's to flip the -99 in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn this into a sweet dynamic programming formula.

We define the **subproblem** as follows:

- We would like to maximize the total sum, while picking either the first two, the first and last, or the last two values of the subarray i, j.

Then the **recurrence** equation looks like this:

```
set OPT(i,j) =
    if i == j
        v[i]
    else if i < j:
        max (
            v[i] + v[i+1] + OPT(i + 2,j),
            v[i] + v[j]   + OPT(i + 1,j + 1),
            v[j] + v[j-1] + OPT(i, j - 2)
        )
    else:
        0
```

The **topological** order: either or both i and j are getting smaller.

Now the **base case** comes when i is equal to j, the value is returned.

And  to come to the **original** problem, calling OPT(0,n-1) returns the maximum sum.

The **time complexity** is O(n^2). Since we use dynamic programming, it enables us to cache all values. Per subproblem call, we use at most O(n) time, and we do this O(n) times.