# What is use of ||= begin....end block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between these snippets?

```ruby
def config
  @config ||= begin
                if config_exists?
                  @config = return some value
                else
                  {}
                end
              end
end
```

```ruby
def config
  @config ||= method
end

def method
  if config_exists?
    return some value
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

I'm confused with the "`begin` ... `end`" block. Does it make any difference in the output? If not, then what is the use of the `begin` ... `end` block here?

Comment: The inner assignment (`@config = `) is redundant.

Comment: `@config = return some value` does not seem like valid ruby - if you can please fix your code, that will help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, you need to be aware that a defined method inherently includes the functionality of a `begin ... end` block.

In the context of exception handling, `def method_name ... end` is functionally equivalent to `begin ... end`. Both can include `rescue` statements for example.

The two blocks of code you have shared are actually identical, and there is no benefit in one over the other ... unless your `method` is needed in more than one place. In that case, you DRY up your code by putting the logic into a single method and calling it from multiple other places.

Answer (score 10):

In your case, you can even omit the `begin ... end` block:

```
@config ||=
  if config_exists?  
    return_some_value
  else
    {}
  end
```

or, using the [ternary if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if):

```
@config ||= config_exists? ? return_some_value : {}
```

> Does it make any difference in output?

It *could* make a difference, because unlike `def ... end`, an `begin ... end` block doesn't create a new variable scope.

Here's a contrived example:

```
def foo
  a = 456  # doesn't affect the other a
end

a = 123
b = foo

p a: a, b: b #=> {:a=>123, :b=>456}
```

Versus:

```
a = 123
b = begin
  a = 456  # overwrites a
end

p a: a, b: b #=> {:a=>456, :b=>456}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to learn more about the variable scope.

Answer (score 8):

Using `||= begin...end` allows you to [memoize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184869/what-is-the-difference-between-memoization-and-dynamic-programming) the result of whatever is run in the `begin...end`. This is useful for caching the result of resource-intensive computation.

Comment: 1. It would be more accurate to say that `@variable ||= code` lets you cache a resource-intensive computation.
2. 
`begin ... end`, however, lets you cache the result of an expression that is made up of multiple statements ("multi-line statements".

Comment: I can remove my comments if you want to edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that will happen differently is if an exception is raised.  For instance, let's say there is a problem in the `config_exists?` method call.  If it raises an exception in the first example your `@config` var will be set to `{}`.  In the second example if the same thing happens your program will crash.

As a side note, there is no need for the `return` keyword here. In fact the example should read as follows.  This is assuming that I understand the intent.

```
def config
  @config ||= 
    begin
      if config_exists?    
        some_value
      else
        {}
      end
    rescue
      {}
    end
end
```

and

```
def config
  @config ||= method
end

def method
  if config_exists?
    some_value
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

Both examples are exactly the same, except if an exception is raised `@config` will still be set to = `some_value` in the first example.

Also, it should be noted that nothing will happen if `@config` already has a value.  The `||=` operators is the same as:

```
@config = some_value if @config.nil?
```

Only set the variable to this value if it is currently nil.

Hope this is helpful and that I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: That's not true - both blocks of code are identical.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but the `begin` & `rescue` keywords are for handling exceptions.   If either `config_exists?` or `some_value` raise an exception, how would it be handled in the second case?

Comment: You're missing the fact that `def` is functionally equivalent to `begin` in terms of exception handling. Also, since neither of these examples include a `rescue` block - nothing good will happen if an exception is raised.

Comment: I suppose his example lacked the `rescue`.  I just assumed it was intended.  Otherwise there is no need for the `begin` and `end`.  Maybe that is the point you are making.

Comment: Jon, you are of course correct.  I just made an assumption about intent.  I guess the fact that it made no sense to me personally to have a `begin` without a `rescue`, put me off track.  That is why i included the `rescue` in my example.  As a side note, is there any good reason to use a `begin` without a `rescue`?  maybe there is a use case I am not aware of?

Comment: You might use it in a loop `begin ... end while conditional`

Comment: Good point. I was aware of, but have never used that construct.  Actually completely slipped my mind.  You get into habits I guess.  Maybe I will find a place to use it this week.  Thanks Jon.

Comment: @AndrewGriffith `my_var = begin v1 = 6 ; v2 = 7 ; v1 * v2 ; end` to assign 42 to `my_var`.