# Converting my recursive function to top down dynamic programming

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have been struggling with this problem all week. The problem is as follows, given such a string, S, of n uppercase letters, describe an efficient way of breaking it into a sequence of valid English words. You may assume the valid(s) function runs in O(1) time. Example of how it should work is like this. Lets say you are given `CABIN` as input. `[A, BIN, IN, CAB, CABIN]` are valid words. Function should return `[[CAB, IN], [CABIN]]`.

I managed to get a recursive function working but can't seem to figure out how to create a dynamic solution.

### Recursive Implementation (JS)

```
var test = 'ABORTTHEPLANMEETATTHEDARKCABIN';
var words = {
    ABORT: true,
    THE: true,
    PLAN: true,
    MEET: true,
    AT: true,
    DARK: true,
    CABIN: true
};
var valid = function(word) {
    if (words[word]) return true;
    return false;
};
String.prototype.suffix = function(i) {
    return this.substring(this.length - i);
};

String.prototype.prefix = function(i) {
    return this.substring(0, i);
};


var breakCode = function(S) {
    var T = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= S.length; i++) {
        var str = S.suffix(i);
        if (valid(str)) {
            if (i < S.length) {
                var prefix = S.prefix(S.length - i);
                var P = breakCode(prefix);
                P.forEach(function(p) {
                    p.push(str);
                    T.push(p);
                });
            } else {
                T.push([str]);
            }
        }
    }
    return T;
}
```

### Non Working Attempt at DP Solution

```
var breakCodeDP = function(S) {
    var T=[];

    for (var i = 1; i <= S.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            var str = S.suffix(j);
            if (valid(str)) {
                if (j < i) {
                    var P = T[i - j];
                    // console.log(T);
                    // P = typeof P === 'undefined'?[]:P;
                    // P.forEach(function(p) {
                    //   if (!Array.isArray(T[i])) T[i] = [];
                    //     T[i].push([p, str]);
                    // });
                } else {
                    T[i] = [str];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please give an example of what the input and output should be

Comment: please add `suffix()` and `valid()`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are allowed to use as part of the 'top-down DP approach'. There seems to be some confusion over the terms (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches). Couldn't you just memoize your recursive solution?

Comment: Sure. The solution should use loops where as a memoized solution would still use recursion.