# runtime complexity of following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given a sequence of as many as 10,000 integers (0 < integer < 100,000), what is the maximum decreasing subsequence? Note that the subsequence does not have to be consecutive.
Recursive Descent Solution

The obvious approach to solving the problem is recursive descent. One need only find the recurrence and a terminal condition. Consider the following solution:

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>


 2  long n, sequence[10000];
 3  main () {
 4       FILE *in, *out;                     
 5       int i;                             
 6       in = fopen ("input.txt", "r");     
 7       out = fopen ("output.txt", "w");   
 8       fscanf(in, "%ld", &n);             
 9       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) fscanf(in, "%ld", &sequence[i]);
10       fprintf (out, "%d\n", check (0, 0, 999999));
11       exit (0);
12  }


13  check (start, nmatches, smallest) {
14      int better, i, best=nmatches;
15      for (i = start; i < n; i++) {
16          if (sequence[i] < smallest) {
17              better = check (i+1, nmatches+1, sequence[i]);
18              if (better > best) best = better;
19          }
20      }
21      return best;
22  }
```

Lines 1-9 and and 11-12 are arguably boilerplate. They set up some standard variables and grab the input. The magic is in line 10 and the recursive routine `check`. The `check` routine knows where it should start searching for smaller integers, the length of the longest sequence so far, and the smallest integer so far. At the cost of an extra call, it terminates automatically when start is no longer within proper range. The `check` routine is simplicity itself. It traverses along the list looking for a smaller integer than the smallest so far. If found, `check` calls itself recursively to find more

i think worst case would be when input is in  completely reverse order
like

> 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

so what is runtime complexity of this algorithm,i am having difficult time finding it...

Comment: It's not called 'maximum decreasing subsequence', but 'longest decreasing subsequence'. It it similar to 'longest increasing subsequence', a classical problem with a dedicated wikipedia page. Have you already checked such resources before asking here?

Comment: Runtime complexity is usually described in three quantities: *average*, *best case* and *worst case*. Which one are you looking for? You already noted the worst case - sum up the recursive calls -, best case is linear, average is going to be more complex.

Comment: In line with what @o900 said, this is an established question. The way your solution looks, cant help but give one suggestion: Try to solve the problem in general while not thinking about time complexity initially. Once you have an established and verified implementation, you can always trim it down or identify a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement matches with Longest increasing sub-sequence problem.

You are not doing any [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches). In worst case your implementation complexity is `O(n^n)`. Because on each recursive call it will generate `(n-1)` recursive call and so on. Try to draw a tree and check number of leaf.
`

```
          n
        / \ \..........
       /   \            \
    (n-1)  (n-1) ...... (n-1)
   /  \
(n-2) (n-2)........(n-2)
`
```

Check out this link[Longest_increasing_subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Also for efficient implementation and more knowledge check this: [Dynamic Programming | Set 3 (Longest Increasing Subsequence)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/)