# Runtime for recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the algorithm above, I can only figure out the runtime for

```
if n==0:
```

is 1 and the runtime for

```
rec_opt(n-1)
```

will be T(n-1).
But I can't figure out the runtime for

```
rec_opt(p[n])
```

and why the recurrence has an exponential closed-form, O(2^n
)

[image]

And furthermore, why this algorithm will be O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rec_opt(p[n])

For recursion call rec_opt(p[n]), there will be another recursion tree which will act like rec_opt(n-1). As `p[n]` could be any value from `1 - n` then we can assume that it will act like a `rec_opt(n)`.

> And furthermore, why this algorithm will be O(n).

On the second part as algorithm doing [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches), it will not calculate same sub-problem again and again. That's why the complexity drastically reduced to `O(n)`.

For more please chech [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Comment: Now I understand rec_opt[n]. But for the runtime of the first algorithm, which is T(n) = 2T(n-1)+c, shouldn't it be O(n)? Because n is the highest term in T(n).

Comment: If you correctly understand rec_opt(p[n]), then complexity will be clear if you try it with pen&paper. Draw a tree and count number of nodes. For the first algorithm you will see that you are doing same task again and again.