# Euler Project #18 - Pythonic approach

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the [18th problem from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) but I'm stuck in the solution. Doing it in a paper I get the same results but I know the answer has a difference of 10 between what I'm getting.

> By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.
>
> ```
>    3
>   7 4
>  2 4 6
> 8 5 9 3
> ```
>
> That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.
>
> Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below:
>
> ```
>                             75
>                           95  64
>                         17  47  82
>                       18  35  87  10
>                     20  04  82  47  65
>                   19  01  23  75  03  34
>                 88  02  77  73  07  63  67
>               99  65  04  28  06  16  70  92
>             41  41  26  56  83  40  80  70  33
>           41  48  72  33  47  32  37  16  94  29
>         53  71  44  65  25  43  91  52  97  51  14
>       70  11  33  28  77  73  17  78  39  68  17  57
>     91  71  52  38  17  14  91  43  58  50  27  29  48
>   63  66  04  68  89  53  67  30  73  16  69  87  40  31
> 04  62  98  27  23  09  70  98  73  93  38  53  60  04  23
> ```
>
> NOTE: As there are only 16384 routes, it is possible to solve this problem by trying every route. However, Problem 67, is the same challenge with a triangle containing one-hundred rows; it cannot be solved by brute force, and requires a clever method! ;o)

Here is my code

```
filename = "triangle.txt"

f = open(filename,"r+")

total = 0

#will store the position of the maximum value in the line
index = 0

#get the first pyramid value
total = [int(x) for x in f.readline().split()][0]

#since it's only one value, the position will start with 0
current_index = 0 

# loop through the lines
for line in f:

    # transform the line into a list of integers
    cleaned_list = [int(x) for x in line.split()]

    # get the maxium value between index and index + 1 (adjacent positions)
    maximum_value_now = max(cleaned_list[current_index],cleaned_list[current_index + 1])

    #print maximum_value_now

    # stores the index to the next iteration        
    future_indexes = [ind for (ind,value) in enumerate(cleaned_list) if value == maximum_value_now]

    # we have more that 2 values in our list with this maximum value
    # must return only that which is greater than our previous index                    
    if (len(future_indexes) > 1):        
        current_index = [i for i in future_indexes if (i >= current_index and i <= current_index + 1)][0]

    else:
        #only one occurence of the maximum value        
        current_index = future_indexes[0]

    # add the value found to the total sum
    total = total + maximum_value_now

print total
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read the entire triangle into a 2d structure. It is handy to note that we can do an affine transformation to the triangle and therefore use an easier coordinate system:

```
   3        \    3
  7 4    ====\   7 4
 2 4 6   ====/   2 4 6
8 5 9 3     /    8 5 9 3
```

It is easy to read this into a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) in Python:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    rows = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in file]
```

Now given x as the horizontal coordinate and y as the vertical coordinate, and them increasing left and down, there are 2 valid moves from (x, y): (x + 1, y + 1) and (x, y + 1). It is as simple as that.

The trick here is now to calculate all the maximum sums for cell in each row. This is called [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The maximum sum is then the maximal sum in the last row.

Actually there is no need to remember anything beyond the sums on the just preceding row, and the sums on the current row. To calculate the maximal row sums `current_sums', we notice that to arrive to position`x`in the latest row, the position must have been`x - 1`or`x`. We choose the maximal value of these, then sum with the current`cell_value`. We can consider any of the numbers outside the triangle as 0 for simplicity as they don't affect the maximal solution here. Therefore we get

```
with open('triangle.txt', 'r') as file:
    triangle = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in file]

previous_sums = []
for row in triangle:
    current_sums = []
    for position, cell_value in enumerate(row):
        sum_from_right = 0 if position >= len(previous_sums) else previous_sums[position]
        sum_from_left = (previous_sums[position - 1]
                         if 0 < position <= len(previous_sums)
                         else 0)
        current_sums.append(max(sum_from_right, sum_from_left) + cell_value)

    previous_sums = current_sums

print('The maximum sum is', max(previous_sums))
```

If you like list comprehensions, the inner loop can be written into one:

```
current_sums = []
for row in triangle:
    len_previous = len(current_sums)
    current_sums = [
        max(0 if pos >= len_previous else current_sums[pos],
            current_sums[pos - 1] if 0 < pos <= len_previous else 0)
        + cell_value
        for pos, cell_value in enumerate(row)
    ]

print('The maximum sum is', max(current_sums))
```

Comment: Well, running your version the maximum value is 1070 and not 1074.
I think this is not the correct logic though.

Comment: @Jetgoncalves indeed :D

Comment: @Jetgoncalves yea, the `0 <=  pos < len` should have been `0 < pos <= len`; fixed

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple recursive solution which uses [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches#6165124)

```
L1 = [
    "   3   ",
    "  7 4  ",
    " 2 4 6 ",
    "8 5 9 3",
]

L2 = [
    "                            75                             ",
    "                          95  64                           ",
    "                        17  47  82                         ",
    "                      18  35  87  10                       ",
    "                    20  04  82  47  65                     ",
    "                  19  01  23  75  03  34                   ",
    "                88  02  77  73  07  63  67                 ",
    "              99  65  04  28  06  16  70  92               ",
    "            41  41  26  56  83  40  80  70  33             ",
    "          41  48  72  33  47  32  37  16  94  29           ",
    "        53  71  44  65  25  43  91  52  97  51  14         ",
    "      70  11  33  28  77  73  17  78  39  68  17  57       ",
    "    91  71  52  38  17  14  91  43  58  50  27  29  48     ",
    "  63  66  04  68  89  53  67  30  73  16  69  87  40  31   ",
    "04  62  98  27  23  09  70  98  73  93  38  53  60  04  23 ",
]

class Max(object):
    def __init__(self, l):
        "parse triangle, initialize cache"
        self.l = l
        self.t = [
            map(int,filter(lambda x:len(x)>0, x.split(" ")))
            for x in l
        ]
        self.cache = {}

    def maxsub(self, r=0, c=0):
        "compute max path starting at (r,c)"
        saved = self.cache.get((r,c))
        if saved:
            return saved

        if r >= len(self.t):
            answer = (0, [], [])
        else:
            v = self.t[r][c]
            s1, l1, c1 = self.maxsub(r+1, c)
            s2, l2, c2 = self.maxsub(r+1, c+1)
            if s1 > s2:
                answer = (v+s1, [v]+l1, [c]+c1)
            else:
                answer = (v+s2, [v]+l2, [c]+c2)
        self.cache[(r,c)] = answer
        return answer

    def report(self):
        "find and report max path"
        m = self.maxsub()
        print
        print "\n".join(self.l)
        print "maxsum:%s\nvalues:%s\ncolumns:%s" % m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Max(L1).report()
    Max(L2).report()
```

Sample output

```
   3
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
maxsum:23
values:[3, 7, 4, 9]
columns:[0, 0, 1, 2]

                            75
                          95  64
                        17  47  82
                      18  35  87  10
                    20  04  82  47  65
                  19  01  23  75  03  34
                88  02  77  73  07  63  67
              99  65  04  28  06  16  70  92
            41  41  26  56  83  40  80  70  33
          41  48  72  33  47  32  37  16  94  29
        53  71  44  65  25  43  91  52  97  51  14
      70  11  33  28  77  73  17  78  39  68  17  57
    91  71  52  38  17  14  91  43  58  50  27  29  48
  63  66  04  68  89  53  67  30  73  16  69  87  40  31
04  62  98  27  23  09  70  98  73  93  38  53  60  04  23
maxsum:1074
values:[75, 64, 82, 87, 82, 75, 73, 28, 83, 32, 91, 78, 58, 73, 93]
columns:[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
```

To solve the 100-row [Project Euler problem 67](https://projecteuler.net/problem=67) we make a small change to `__main__`

```
def main():
    with file('triangle.txt') as f:
        L = f.readlines()
    Max(L).report()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Last lines of output:

```
maxsum:7273
values:[59, 73, 52, 53, 87, 57, 92, 81, 81, 79, 81, 32, 86, 82, 97, 55, 97, 36, 62, 65, 90, 93, 95, 54, 71, 77, 68, 71, 94, 8, 89, 54, 42, 90, 84, 91, 31, 71, 93, 94, 53, 69, 73, 99, 89, 47, 80, 96, 81, 52, 98, 38, 91, 78, 90, 70, 61, 17, 11, 75, 74, 55, 81, 87, 89, 99, 73, 88, 95, 68, 37, 87, 73, 77, 60, 82, 87, 64, 96, 65, 47, 94, 85, 51, 87, 65, 65, 66, 91, 83, 72, 24, 98, 89, 53, 82, 57, 99, 98, 95]
columns:[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 27, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 34, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 49, 49, 50, 51, 52, 52, 53]
```

On my Mac it returns the answer immediately.  Here is a `timeit` measurement:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'from p067 import main' main
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0181 usec per loop
```

Comment: Well, looking at your output I guess I haven't understood the problem.
Since I'm starting from the value 75, shouldn't the algorithm choose the number 95 in the 2nd row? The adjacent numbers of 75 are 95 and 64. Since 95 > 64, this should be the number chosen. Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: That 95 in the second row is indeed inticing, but the path down 64 leads to larger sums later.

Comment: Specifically they both lead to 87 but 75 + 64 + 82 = 221 vs 75 + 95 + 47 = 217.

Comment: Indeed. Well, my algorithm doesn't work like that. It's using the information direct from the neighbors to decide which direction to take, since this is the pattern I could imagine from the example it gave me.

I'm gonna do a research about this theme.

Thanks!

Comment: @Jetgoncalves dynamic programming and optimal substructure are the keywords here. This task doesn't require dynamic programming, but 67 does.

Comment: This answer readily solves p67 as well - see edit for results.  Also see this question: [Dynamic programming and memoization: bottom-up vs top-down approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches#6165124)

Comment: Love to know why this is downvoted given that it's a solution that's both efficient and correct.