# Example of non-Euclidean tabulation in Dynamic Programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

In the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches) regarding Dynamic Programming, the authors mentioned that:

> Tabulation - You can also think of dynamic programming as a "table-filling" algorithm (though usually multidimensional, this 'table' may have non-Euclidean geometry in very rare cases).

What are some examples of this 'non-Euclidean' geometry tabulation the authors referred to?

Comment: Could just be a way to say that the subproblems are not always enumerated or represented as a table. See, for example, [Maximum Independent set in a tree](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/s99cs170/notes/dynamic2.pdf).

Comment: (I'm the author of the answer you linked.) Your question was brought to my attention just now. I replied in a comment under the linked response. Cheers.

Comment: Such a question is better served as a comment under an existing answer. (Though in this case I understand, since I (the author of the linked answer) did not notice someone else's prior comment asking for the same clarification.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic programming and memoization: bottom-up vs top-down approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches)

Comment: As a result, I've voted to close this as a duplicate, although that connection is tenuous.