# Why would you use Top Down Dynamic Programming over Bottom Up?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm a bit confused about Top down style Dynamic Programming. Why would you ever implement it in practice? Wouldn't using a Bottom Up program always be faster as the Top Down involves recursion (so more overhead) while Bottom Up involves loops? Thanks guys.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164629/dynamic-programming-and-memoization-bottom-up-vs-top-down-approaches

Answer (score 2):

CLRS seemed to provide a good answer to my question.

Benefits of Top-Down are that you only need to solve subproblems that are definitely required, so if some subproblems are in the subproblem space and do not need to be solved, you'd be wasting computational resources solving them with bottom up.

Would be interested in other answers/reasons though. Thanks!